# Django error while template rendering: NoReverseMatch found

Tags: python, django, django-templates

The following piece of code is throwing an error. I searched for the solution, but couldn't find anything which is pertaining to my scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#urls.py
url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)\/(?P<token>.+)/$', 
    app_name.password_reset_confirm,name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
```

I need to render an email template as a string in my view.

```
#views.py
from django.template import Context, loader
t = loader.get_template('app_name/email.html')
message = t.render(Context({"domain":"foo.com","protocol":"https"}))
user.email_user(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)
```

Following is the html file, simplified for SO:

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
<html>
    <body>
        {% block reset_link %}<br />
            <a href="{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/accounts/password/reset/confirm/{{uid}}/{{token}}">{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/accounts/password/reset/confirm/{{uid}}/{{token}}</a>
            <br />
        {% endblock %}
        {% trans "Thanks for using our product!" %}<br /><br />
        {% blocktrans %}Regards, <br />{{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}
    </body>
</html>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Error Traceback:

```
NoReverseMatch                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 message = t.render(Context({"domain":"foo.com","protocol":"https"}))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.pyc in render(self, context)
    138         context.render_context.push()
    139         try:
--> 140             return self._render(context)
    141         finally:
    142             context.render_context.pop()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.pyc in _render(self, context)
    132 
    133     def _render(self, context):
--> 134         return self.nodelist.render(context)
    135 
    136     def render(self, context):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.pyc in render(self, context)
    828         for node in self:
    829             if isinstance(node, Node):
--> 830                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
    831             else:
    832                 bit = node

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.pyc in render_node(self, node, context)
     72     def render_node(self, node, context):
     73         try:
---> 74             return node.render(context)
     75         except Exception as e:
     76             if not hasattr(e, 'django_template_source'):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.pyc in render(self, context)
     31         old_setting = context.autoescape
     32         context.autoescape = self.setting
---> 33         output = self.nodelist.render(context)
     34         context.autoescape = old_setting
     35         if self.setting:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.pyc in render(self, context)
    828         for node in self:
    829             if isinstance(node, Node):
--> 830                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
    831             else:
    832                 bit = node

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.pyc in render_node(self, node, context)
     72     def render_node(self, node, context):
     73         try:
---> 74             return node.render(context)
     75         except Exception as e:
     76             if not hasattr(e, 'django_template_source'):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.pyc in render(self, context)
     52         if block_context is None:
     53             context['block'] = self
---> 54             result = self.nodelist.render(context)
     55         else:
     56             push = block = block_context.pop(self.name)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.pyc in render(self, context)
    828         for node in self:
    829             if isinstance(node, Node):
--> 830                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
    831             else:
    832                 bit = node

 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.pyc in render_node(self, node, context)
     72     def render_node(self, node, context):
     73         try:
---> 74             return node.render(context)
     75         except Exception as e:
     76             if not hasattr(e, 'django_template_source'):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.pyc in render(self, context)
    422                         # the path relative to the project. This makes a

    423                         # better error message.

--> 424                         raise e
    425             else:
    426                 if self.asvar is None:

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': '', u'token': ''}' not found.
```

Comment: can you show us the `urls.py` ? this error occurs when the `{% url %}` in template (or foobar.render() in the view) try to match an unexisting url which should be defined in urls.py

Comment: @FoxMaSk I have added the relevant url in urls.py . But I'm not using `{% url %}` in my html template.

Comment: did you do a `return` after `message=` ?

Comment: I use the message for sending mail and after successful sending, I do `return HttpResponseRedirect`.

Comment: where do you use the name `auth_password_reset_confirm` you've defined in the `urls.py` ?? in your template you should drop all the string in the A node and replace it by `{% url auth_password_reset_confirm parm1,parm2,etc %}`

Answer (score 0):

As FoxMaSk has commented you should replace:

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/accounts/password/reset/confirm/{{uid}}/{{token}}
```

with:

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'auth_password_reset_confirm' uid36=uid token=token %}
```

Note the single quotes around the view name in the url, this is required in Django 1.5+ (not sure what version you are using).

More importantly I believe the error lies here:

```
message = t.render(Context({"domain":"foo.com","protocol":"https"}))
```

You are not passing your uid or token into the context when rendering the template which is why you are seeing empty values in the traceback message for these variables:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': '', u'token': ''}' not found.
```